# TestNG @BeforeMethod and @AfterMethod run by groups

Tags: java, testng

I want to have @beforeMethod and @AfterMethod per group for setup and teardown.

I tried to do something like this but it executes the start()/end() and start2()/end2() always.

```
public class DemoTest
{
    @BeforeMethod(groups = "1")
    public void start()
    {
        System.out.println("Start");
    }

    @Test(groups = "1")
    public void test1()
    {
        System.out.println("test1");
    }

    @Test(groups = "1")
    public void test2()
    {
        System.out.println("test2");
    }

    @AfterMethod(groups = "1")
    public void end()
    {
        System.out.println("End");
    }

    @BeforeMethod(groups = "2")
    public void start2()
    {
        System.out.println("Start2");
    }

    @Test(groups = "2")
    public void test12()
    {
        System.out.println("test12");
    }

    @Test(groups = "2")
    public void test22()
    {
        System.out.println("test22");
    }

    @AfterMethod(groups = "2")
    public void end2()
    {
        System.out.println("End2");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Start
Start2
test1
End
End2
Start
Start2
test12
End
End2
Start
Start2
test2
End
End2
Start
Start2
test22
End
End2
```

I want this output to be:

```
Start
test1
End
Start
test2
End
Start2
test12
End2
Start2
test22
End2
```

I am not sure how to achieve this? Need help here.

Answer (score 3):

"I want to have `@BeforeMethod` and `@AfterMethod` per group for setup and teardown."

What you want is called `@BeforeGroups` and `@AfterGroups`.
[Further info.](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations)